# Subselect, Group by and Having Count with criteria in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT ap.person_id FROM 
     (SELECT distinct ac.person_id person_id,ac.user_id 
      FROM zrm_actor ac WHERE ac.deleted != 1) ap 
WHERE person_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY person_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

How can I write this query with criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create sub-criteria from a sub-select that it's not match an entity.

```
SELECT distinct ac.person_id person_id,ac.user_id 
 FROM zrm_actor ac WHERE ac.deleted != 1
```

The above query don't match with any entity, so there is no way to create sub-criteria from it.